# CSS: maintain floating and nth-child clearing of objects if elements are display:none

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design, css-selectors

This is tricky and tough to explain, that's why I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4rXM/embedded/result/) to visualize my problem.

I have a grid of elements where every fourth element is cleared left `clear:left`.

I have a toggle (in my real case a filter) that is hiding some of those floated elements and I want to move the rest up and still maintain the 4by4 grid.

```
<div class="item"> 1 </div>
<div class="item"> 2 </div>
…

.item:nth-of-type(4n+1) { clear: left; }
```

See this examample: http://jsfiddle.net/K4rXM/

When clicking the "Do It!" link the `nth-of-type`rule is kind of neglected. Suddenly all elements float to the left and there is no clear after the 4th element.

This is actually just slightly describing my problem. Actually it is a bit more complicated with a responsive layout like i have it.

Any ideas and tipps for me? Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: Tried hiding by `.hide` and using `:not(.hide)`?

Comment: It's still counting the hidden ones but because they're hidden they don't affect the flow.

Comment: @PetrMarek Yes I tried that, no effect however. Doesn't change a thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.item').hide();
$('.call').show();
$('.item:visible').each(function (i) {
if (i % 4 == 0) $(this).addClass('clearLeft');
});
});


.clearLeft{clear:left;}
```

As in my comment it's still counting the hidden divs, you have to check which are visible, then apply a class.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/K4rXM/4/

Comment: Thank you, but how can I apply the same principle to my real example? Any ideas on that too?

Comment: The fiddle I supplied is applied to your example, just add the jquery click function to the vortraege click event no?

Comment: In that case you'd have to take into consideration the window resize event and change where the class is being applied depending on the size of the window. You really only have to do it for the 4 and 2 columns though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/K4rXM/6/ Updated to take window size into account. You'll have to adjust the point at which the event triggers obviously, the 640 is just approximate to get the event to work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you, however I do have one last missunderstanding problem. Your code `( i % 4 == 0 )` applies a `.clearLeft` to every 4th element. However as you can see in my "live" example, when clicking the word "Vorträge" the elements don't even float up like the're supposed to. I have a "break" after the 2nd item so how can I move them up?

Comment: Have you implemented the code above? It doesn't look like it is, it actually looks like the only style changing is the display:none. The code above applies clearLeft (which is just a class with clear:left; defined in the CSS) to every 4th visible item, instead of just every 4th item.

Comment: Yeah, but the pre-defined CSS rule `nth-of-type` is still applied. So even though every visible 4th element gets a `.clearLeft` class applied the `nth-of-type` selector cleares every 4th element. So in my case, when I click "Vorträge" there is a break after the 2nd visible item, because it is actually the 4th dom-item in that list (2 items are hidden, when Vorträge is clicked) … am I completely wrong here? Are we talking about the same. I can see your Jsfiddle is clearly working however the normal floating is not workin in my live example.

Comment: That's what I find strange, the hidden ones shouldn't be affecting the flow, much like they weren't in your fiddle example.

Comment: Yeah, but you can see what I'm talking about, right? In my live example they are not floating after I click the Filter. That is what's strange to me. I totally get your approach, however I can't find out why my boxes are not floating in the first place.